# Behaviour of local and class variables in java

Tags: java, static, class-level

I am new in Java Programming language. 
I am familiar with C and C++ but unable to understand the behaviour of the below program.

```java
public class Test {
    static int x = 11;
    private int y = 33;
    public void method1(int x) {
        Test t = new Test();
        this.x = 22;
        y = 44;    
        System.out.println("Test.x: " + Test.x);
        System.out.println("t.x: " + t.x);
        System.out.println("t.y: " + t.y);
        System.out.println("y: " + y);
    }    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.method1(5);
    }
}
```

Correct Output:

```
Test.x: 22
t.x: 22
t.y: 33
y: 44
```

Output expected:

```
Test.x: 22
t.x: 22
t.y: 44   // As variable y is modified inside the function.
y: 44
```

Even changing the line from `y = 44;`  to `this.y = 44;` is not giving the expected output.

Comment: `y` is not a static field. It's an instance field. So each Test instance has its own y. The method modifies `y` (i.e. `this.y`), not `t.y`. If you paint your car in black, your dad's car doesn't become black. Same here.

Comment: This would have given you the same result in C++ too, with which you say you are familiar. Why are you surprised that Java behaves the same way?

Comment: I thought it may be problem with some variable scope in Java which I am unable to understand. But after knowing the actual reason behind this behaviour, yes the same  will be in C++ too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not referring to the actual object created. You are reffering the variable from other instance which have fresh variables.

```
        Test t = new Test();
        this.x = 22;
        y = 44;

        System.out.println("Test.x: " + Test.x);
        System.out.println("t.x: " + t.x);
        System.out.println("t.y: " + t.y);
        System.out.println("y: " + y);
```

If you look close at very first line `Test t = new Test();`

you are not calling method1 on that particular instance where y is assigning to 44. Hence you seeing the top level value.

It will be more clear if you rename your instances. Instead of `t` always.

That is the reason for the confusion and also, you call `method1()` inside that might lead to you a endless loop.

Answer (score 2):

in `method1` you have two objects `t` and `this` (current object) and the line

```
y = 44; // equivalent to this.y = 44
```

is setting the value of current object , so

```
this.y == 44; or y == 44;
t.y == 33;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Basic Difference between static and non-static variables**

```
class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    static String collegeName;
}
```

For every object of Students `non-static` attributes id and name will be loaded into memory with its initial values (0 & null), id and name can be different for each object. But collegeName will only be loaded once, that's when class is loaded for execution. So for every object of `Student` will have same college name. That's what is meant by `static`.

**Accessing static and non-static variables**

```
class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    static String collegeName;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = Student.collgeName;
        String s2 = collgeName;
        Student student = new Student();
        String s3 = student.name;
        int id = student.id;
    }
}
```

Static variables can be accessed directly by using their name or using the help of class name. When there is a static global variable and a local variable, the static one should be used along with the class name

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = Student.collgeName;
    String collgeName = "foo";
    String output = collgeName;
}
```

Here `output` will be having value "**foo**". Local variable is always having higher priority that global static variable and that's why `String output = s1;` will give value for output as `null`.

Inside a static block `non-static` variables must be accessed with the help of reference variables (We have to create an object). Main method is static that's why we had to create object of `Student` to access the values of `id` and `name`, otherwise it will give compile time error.

**Blind rule regarding non-static blocks**

Every non-static blocks will be using a default `this` keyword representing current reference on which the block is invoked when a class level (static as well as non-static) variables are used. Sample java code

```
class Student {
     private int id;
     private String name;
     static String collegeName;
     void setData() {
         id = 1;
         name = "foo";
         collegeName = "FooCollege";
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Student student = new Student();
         student.setData();
     }
}
```

This is what happens when the same code is compiled to get the class file

```
class Student {
     private int id;
     private String name;
     static String collegeName;
     void setData() {
         this.id = 1;
         this.name = "foo";
         this.collegeName = "FooCollege"; // which will be again as Student.collegeName
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Student student = new Student();
         student.setData();
     }
}
```

Here `this` representing the reference variable `student` from main method. ***Represents the reference variable on which the block is invoked.***

Coming to the question, main method creates a `Test` object and on its reference `method1()` is invoked. So inside `method1` **this** is nothing but reference variable `t` created in main  method and `t` is the local reference variable of the method. Now lets re-write the code in class file format

```
public void method1(int x) {
   Test t = new Test();
   this.x = 22;  //  or Test.x = 22;
   y = 44;  //  or this.y = 44;
   /* 
       Test object inside method1 and main method are in two different locations.
       When we write this.y = 44; the y inside the main method object will be changed and not the one created inside method1.
   */
   System.out.println("Test.x: " + Test.x);
   System.out.println("t.x: " + t.x);
   System.out.println("t.y: " + t.y); // means the y inside the object created inside method1
   System.out.println("y: " + y); // means the y inside the object created inside main method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the point that you should understand is that y = 44 or this.y = 44 does not modify the t.y, if you want to modify the value of t.y you can do this: 
t.y = 44;